# Find number of distinct arrays

Tags: combinatorics

We are given an array $[a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n]$

Define an operation :  select any one element of array and multiply by $-1$

We apply this operation $x$ times.

How many distinct arrays we can get after the operation is done $x$ times ?

Comment: Where did you come across this question? Have you made any progress yourself towards answering it?

Comment: @MikePierce no progress so far and a friend of mine gave me (I don't know from where he got it)

Comment: Don't answer this question, it is from a live competition:  https://www.codechef.com/JUNE16/problems/CHEFARK

Comment: Is the array positive definite?